# Any rule to find the sign of a "vice-versa" second partial derivative if we know the sign of an original one?

Tags: derivatives, economics

We have a function, say, a profit function of a monopoly firm
$$Y=R(Q)-C(Q,b)$$
where:

$R$ is the revenue function;

$Q$ is the output quantity

$C$ is the cost function

$b$ is the price of an input (in this particular problem it's oil)

We need to determine the sign of $\frac {dQ}{db}$.

One clue given is that: $$\frac {\partial^2 C}{\partial b \partial Q} > 0$$
which means that the marginal cost of producing one more unit increases when the input price increases.

However, as comparative statics suggest, the thing we need is the $\frac {\partial^2 Y}{\partial Q \partial b}$, that actually implies finding the sign of $-\frac {\partial^2 C}{\partial Q \partial b}$.

The question is, if we know the sign of one partial second erivative $\frac {\partial^2 C}{\partial b \partial Q} > 0$, is there any rule that helps us find the sign of $\frac {\partial^2 C}{\partial Q \partial b}$ (the "vice-versa" partial second derivative) in a straightforward way?

Comment: As $R$ is a function of Q only, isnt $\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial b \partial Q}=\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial b \partial Q}$ as $\frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial b \partial Q}= 0$?

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, but does it imply that $\frac {dQ}{db} >0$ too? As there is $\partial b \partial Q$ in the denominator, not the $\partial Q \partial b$ (and btw, $b$ is exogenous variable so $\frac {db}{dQ}$ doesn't make sense)

Comment: what is the relation between $Q$ and $b$?

Comment: @vidyarthi The change of output quantity $Q$ (endogenous variable, as the supplier may adjust the output) if the input price $b$ (exogenous variable, as the price is determined by some other forces outside of this model) changes. The common sense says that it should be $<0$ (as you will produce less when the marginal revenue is the same as $R$ depends only on $Q$ but the marginal costs increase), but the question is to show it (as the problem asks us to find $\frac {dQ}{db}$

Comment: As $\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial b \partial Q}=\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial Q \partial b}$, I hope the answer is achieved through comparative statics, isnt it?

Comment: @vidyarthi Thanks, now it does make sense!

Comment: The usual condition for $\partial^2f/\partial x \partial y = \partial^2f/\partial y \partial x$ at point $a$ is that the two partials are continuous in a open set around $a$.  See Spivak, calculus on manifolds, thm 2-5.